# How do I get Twitter follow request with the Tweetstream Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, twitter, tweetstream

According to this Ars Technica tutorial, "the streaming API makes it easy to detect when the user gets a new follower. To detect follow event objects, look for the "event" key and check if it has the string "follow" as the value."

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2010/04/tutorial-use-twitters-new-real-time-stream-api-in-python/2/

The tweetstream gem supposedly exposes all methods from the API. However I can't figure out, how to get to those follow requests!

Any ideas?

Comment: Think I found it in the code (this part isn't really documented), line 361 in client.rb "# Set a Proc to be run on userstream events"

Answer (score 0):

The tweetstream gem is fairly complete, but sometimes you need to delve into the source to find stuff:

```
client.on_event(:follow) do |event|
  p event[:source][:screen_name]
end
```

https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream/blob/master/lib/tweetstream/client.rb#L375 :)